# Fractional Sobolev space norm given by Laplace Beltrami operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, smooth-manifolds, harmonic-functions, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I'm currently reading Lions and Magenes *Non-Homogeneous Boundary Value Problems and Applications* and I'm stuck at one point.

Let $\Gamma$ be the smooth boundary of an open bounded subset $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. We can define the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta$. Denote the eigenvalues of $-\Delta$ by $\lambda_j$ and the orthonormalized (in $L^2(\Gamma)$) eigenfunctions by $w_j$.

At the beginning of the book they use local charts to define the spaces $H^s(\Gamma)$ for $s\in\mathbb{R}$.
Later they state that we can equivalently define
$H^{2m}(\Gamma)$ for $m\geq 0$
by
$$H^{2m}(\Gamma)=\lbrace u: u\in L^2(\Gamma), \ \Delta_\Gamma^m u\in L^2(\Gamma)\rbrace$$

with equivalent norm $\Vert u\Vert_{L^2(\Gamma)}+\Vert\Delta_\Gamma^m u\Vert_{L^2(\Gamma)}$. Then they say by interpolation we can show for $s\in\mathbb{R}$ $$H^s(\Gamma)=\lbrace u: u\in\mathcal{D}'(\Gamma) \ \sum_{j=1}^\infty \lambda_j^{2s}\vert \langle u,w_j\rangle\vert^2<\infty\rbrace.$$

What puzzles me, or rather what I wonder about:

Is the norm on $H^s$ given by $\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty \lambda_j^{2s}\vert \langle u,w_j\rangle\vert^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}$? Looking at the case $s=2m$ and the norm of the graph, I would think that it should be something like $\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty (1+\lambda_j^{2})^s\vert \langle u,w_j\rangle\vert^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}$ for $s\geq 0$? But what about $s<0$? What can we say about $\lambda_j$?

Comment: Might have to migrate to mathoverflow but I would leave it here for a day or two. The answering crowds do overlap.

Comment: The first norm seems like a homogeneous norm (I would usually write $H^s_0$ or $\dot H^s$); so you would identify functions that differ by a constant.